# Firebase realtime database emulator ignoring rules when access_token is set in REST query?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-tools

Every queries (at least from the REST API) seems handled like admin query when access_token is set (even with a dummy value), ignoring any rule:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    ".read": false
  }
}
```

```
i  database: Change detected, updating rules for my-project-default-rtdb...
 +  database: Rules updated.
```

`POST http://localhost:9000/test.json?ns=my-project-default-rtdb`=>`401 Unauthorized`

`POST http://localhost:9000/test.json?ns=my-project-default-rtdb&access_token=foo`=>`200 OK`

- Rules appear loaded at `http://localhost:9000/.inspect/coverage?ns=my-project-default-rtdb`
- no user are created with Firebase Auth, the token is just "foo".

Is there a settings to enable proper auth support for the Realtime Database emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [authenticate a rest to the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) to the production Realtime Database with an `access_token`, the user is a collaborator on the Firebase project (or it's a service account) and has full access to the database. This type of access does not have to abide by the security rules of the database, similar to how such a collaborator can access all data in the Firebase console. From the documentation:

> **Google OAuth2 access tokens** - Typically, the ability to read from and write to the Realtime Database is governed by Realtime Database Rules. But, you can access your data from a server and grant that server full read and write access to your data with a Google OAuth2 access token generated from a service account.

It sounds like the emulator may not be actually validating the token, but the logic seems the same: using `access_token` grants access to the entire database, bypassing the security rules.

This also explains why you don't see the user in Firebase Authentication: this type of access does not use Firebase Authentication at all, and is intended for use with collaborators on the project and service accounts.

If you want to access the database as a regular user, [authenticate with an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token) in the `auth` parameter instead.